# Question regarding Real Analysis and epsilon-delta

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, epsilon-delta

I do not know how to solve question 1, part 2. I cannot find Delta in terms of epsilon, a, and g(a) solely. Can someone explain how to find delta and what the answer is? I couldn't get started because I do not fully understand this concept. Thanks! [image]

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4928/290189) Please use MathJax. See [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020).
Please [don't use pictures for critical portions](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/20529/290189) of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not viewable to those who use screen readers.
Please read [this post](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9960) for information on writing a good question. People will be more willing to help if you [edit] your question to include an explanation of your own attempts.

Answer (score 1):

Note that if 
\begin{equation}
\left\lvert\frac{1}{1+x^{2}}-\frac{1}{1+a^{2}}\right\rvert\leq \epsilon^{1/2},
\end{equation}
then clearly $|g\circ f(x)-g\circ f(a)|<\epsilon$ is satisfied. Can you take it from here?

Comment: I'm sorry but I cant